# ggplot multiple panels, multiple curves

Tags: r, ggplot2

This code makea this plot, which is a scatter of two variables factored by city and by grade:

```
ggplot(e,aes(x=pre_c,y=post_c,col=grade))+geom_point()+facet_grid(grade~city)
```

[image: my plot]

Can anyone suggest how to add the second set of black dots in the picture, which are a scatter of another pair of variables? This first set is the control and the second the treated group in this example.

Comment: The simplest way is to add: `geom_point(data = control, aes(x= pre_c, y=post_c), colour = "black")`.  You can also `melt` your data to get control and treatment data into the same column, then plot the points according to type (control or treatment).

Comment: In addition to `melt` from `reshape2`, you can also use `gather` from the `tidyr` package.  This is valid in the the 2nd suggestion from @oshun.